# Unable to access Dialogflow webhook Parameters

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I have a webhook in DF however my web service cannot seem to get the JSON messages sent from DF. How to access the object that would have DF's responses using node.js. Currently, my function is accepting a variable called req but req.body or req.queryResult doesn't seem to access DF parameters. Any help would be appreciated. My code is below which doesn't print any parameters from DF:

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.body.queryResult.parameters);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't indicate what middleware, if any, you have setup for this route.

You *should* be using the [express.json()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json) middleware, which will set `req.body` to a JavaScript object that should, at a minimum, contain the `queryResult` attribute.